# How to use @RolesAllowed with Keycloak and Java?

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, keycloak

I'm new to web applications and I played around with keycloak to find out how all this authorization/authentification stuff works.
I also had a look at the [Quickstart Github Repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts) and tried out [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/keycloak/keycloak-quickstart-example) quickstart by mastertheboss.

In this tutorial there is just a simple `REST` service

```java
package annotation_test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {
    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    public String getHello () 
    {
        return "hello world!";
    } 
    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SimpleProperty getPropertyJSON ()
    {
        SimpleProperty p = new SimpleProperty("key","value");
        return p;
    }
    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public SimpleProperty getPropertyXML () 
    {
        SimpleProperty p = new SimpleProperty("key","value");
        return p;
    }
}
```

Now I made the following changes:

1. Add three roles: `admin`, `user`, `employee` and three users each.
2. Edit the `web.xml` as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>employee</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>employee</role-name>
</security-role>
</web-app>
```

Now the `REST` endpoints are only available to users in the roles "`admin`" and "`employee`".
Now I wanted to play around with the security annotations and tried the following:

```java
package annotation_test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {
    @GET
    @Path("/text")
    public String getHello () 
    {
        return "hello world!";
    }

    @RolesAllowed("employee")
    @GET
    @Path("/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SimpleProperty getPropertyJSON ()
    {
        SimpleProperty p = new SimpleProperty("key","value");
        return p;
    }

    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public SimpleProperty getPropertyXML () 
    {
        SimpleProperty p = new SimpleProperty("key","value");
        return p;
    }
}
```

But as long as the user has the role "`admin`" or "`employee`" it has access to everything.

How is this annotation thing done correctly? I want to use the roles I've defined in keycloak to restrict the access in my code using annotations such that I have to change the code as less as possible. I found some examples with SpringBoot but I don't want to change my setting...

Answer (score 0):

I think your "problem" is located in the `web.xml`. Here you set the roles `admin` and `employee` to be allowed for all resources (because of the url-pattern /*).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Somehow my included jars where a mess. After looking through carefully it finally worked out. Im not sure what exactly went wrong, but thanks for your help.